# React infinity props on console.log

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have faced an issue, let imagine you have an object that takes a component, then this component takes a whole object as a reference, in the current situation after console.log it shows recursive references. Maybe that is a normal case, it is just interesting that how console.log keeps infinity references. It displays data after clicking expand button on the browser inspect tool.

I have added the sample code below.
There is also [react application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xe2sfx?file=sample.tsx) link.

```
  const SampleComponent = () => {
      const dynamicState = {
        component: <></>
      };
      return <A dynamicState={dynamicState} />;
    };
    
    interface AProps {
      dynamicState: {
        component: JSX.Element;
      };
    }
    
    const A = (props: AProps) => {
      const { dynamicState } = props;
      dynamicState.component = <B dynamicState={dynamicState} />;
      console.log(dynamicState);
      return <></>;
    };
    
    
    const B = (props: AProps) => {
      return <></>;
    };
```

**Console.log result**

```
{component: {…}}
      component:
         $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
          key: null
             props:
             dynamicState:
              component:
                 $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
                 key: null
                 props:
                  dynamicState:
                             ....
```